# paypal Adaptive Payment-You do not have permission to constrain funding sources

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Iam getting error when i try to make payment using paypal adaptive payment. iam getting success ack in sanbox. but its not working in live.i googled it , can't find a propoer answer.
below is my pay request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PayRequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
<requestEnvelope xmlns=""><detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>
<errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage></requestEnvelope>
<actionType xmlns="">PAY</actionType><cancelUrl xmlns="">cancel url</cancelUrl>
<clientDetails xmlns=""><applicationId xmlns="">APP-2JdfdfdfdfK4691244F</applicationId>
<ipAddress xmlns="">122.166.240.144</ipAddress>
</clientDetails>
<currencyCode xmlns="">GBP</currencyCode>
<feesPayer xmlns="">EACHRECEIVER</feesPayer>
<fundingConstraint xmlns="">
<allowedFundingType xmlns="">
<fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
<fundingType xmlns="">ECHECK</fundingType>
</fundingTypeInfo><fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
<fundingType xmlns="">BALANCE</fundingType></fundingTypeInfo>
<fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
    <fundingType xmlns="">CREDITCARD</fundingType>
</fundingTypeInfo>
</allowedFundingType>
</fundingConstraint>
<ipnNotificationUrl xmlns="">notification url</ipnNotificationUrl>
<memo xmlns="">test</memo><preapprovalKey xmlns="">PA-35656565E907913S</preapprovalKey>
<receiverList xmlns=""><receiver xmlns=""><amount xmlns="">100</amount>
    <email xmlns="">anooj08@gmail.com</email>
    <invoiceId xmlns="">123456789</invoiceId>
    <paymentType xmlns="">SERVICE</paymentType>
</receiver>
</receiverList>
<sender><useCredentials xmlns="">false</useCredentials></sender>
<account xmlns="">
    <phone xmlns=""></phone>
</account>
<returnUrl xmlns="">redirect url</returnUrl><reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError xmlns="">TRUE</reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError>
</PayRequest>
```

and iam getting this response

```
Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 550001
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => You do not have permission to constrain funding sources
                    [Parameter] => 
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

        )

    [Ack] => Failure
    [Build] => 6520082
    [CorrelationID] => 57dbec06d371f
    [Timestamp] => 2013-06-28T21:43:10.518-07:00
    [PayKey] => 
    [PaymentExecStatus] => 
    [RedirectURL] => 
    [XMLRequest] => my xml request
    [XMLResponse] =>response
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check fundingConstraint:

```
<fundingConstraint>
<fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
<fundingType xmlns="">ECHECK</fundingType>
</fundingTypeInfo>
<fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
<fundingType xmlns="">BALANCE</fundingType>
</fundingTypeInfo>
<fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
<fundingType xmlns="">CREDITCARD</fundingType>
</fundingTypeInfo>
</fundingConstraint>
```

as addressed [here](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/2102_pp_adaptivepayments.pdf) :

```
fundingConstraint New field: ap:FundingConstraint Specifies a list of allowed
funding     types for the payment. This list can be in any order. If this field is
omitted, the payment can be funded by any funding type that is supported by Adaptive
Payments. NOTE: This feature is available for applications with special permission level.
```

Comment: As @kwishnu mentioned above you would need the permission for setting the funding constraints. But looks like you are setting all three types anyways - so you don't need to set the funding constraints. Just  remove the field. If you really need permission to set this - please submit your request from apps.paypal.com as part of your application request.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following code from your pay request and try surely it will work.

```
<fundingConstraint xmlns="">
<allowedFundingType xmlns="">
<fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
<fundingType xmlns="">ECHECK</fundingType>
</fundingTypeInfo><fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
<fundingType xmlns="">BALANCE</fundingType></fundingTypeInfo>
<fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
    <fundingType xmlns="">CREDITCARD</fundingType>
</fundingTypeInfo>
</allowedFundingType>
</fundingConstraint>
```